# Neither libtoolize nor glibtoolize could be found

Tags: c++, linux, ssh, compilation, libssh2

I'm trying to compile a .cpp file but I must install libssh2. I have downloaded the package from libssh2.org and when I enter: ./buildconf I'm getting:

**Neither libtoolize nor glibtoolize could be found!**

I don't know what to do, I have included in the header libssh2.h ( #include  ) and also the file does exists in the same folder where I have the source file what I'm trying to compile.

Comment: Do you have libtool installed?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It is provided by the package libtool.

On Ubuntu you'd simply

```
sudo apt-get install libtool
```

see also http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/libtoolize.1.html

Comment: and on RedHat... yum install libtool

Comment: libtool provides libtoolize, but what package provides glibtoolize?

Comment: When Homebrew installs libtool on a system that already has libtool (MacOS 10.12, Sierra, in my case), it installs to /usr/local/Cellar/libtool en prepends the existing installation with a 'g'.  Thus, weirdly, one ends up with /usr/local/glibtool en /usr/local/glibtoolize. When avrdude's ./bootstrip could not find libtoolize, changing the command to glibtoolize solved to problem.